# How to manage Unfold precompiling error: _iszero not defined?

Tags: julia, unfold

On a new computer I was trying to run Unfold and UnfoldMakie. See this error in both cases.
Like something wrong with the MutableArithmetics library.
Any idea how to manage it?

[image]

Also get this after update of MakieCore package:

[image]

Versions:

- Julia 1.8.0.
- Unfold v0.3.11
- UnfoldMakie v0.1.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out the problem:

First, I created a new environment/project.
https://pkgdocs.julialang.org/v1/environments/

Second, activated it in the notebook.
Third, installed problematic libraries through this code:

```
import Pkg
p = "Unfold"
Pkg.add(p)
Pkg.build(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems as a solution:

These packages work in the julia envv1.7, but do not work in v1.8.

In VScode you can change it here:

[image]